# How to use AWS secret manager with Amplify

Tags: aws-amplify, aws-secrets-manager

I have AWS Amplify Apps and currently the passwords are stored in Amplify environment variables.
I am trying to use AWS secret manager to store my secrets and use it in my Amplify project

I checked AWS documentation (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/environment-variables.html) they mention to enter parameter in this format(For Name, enter a parameter in the format /amplify/{your_app_id}/{your_backend_environment_name}/{your_parameter_name} )
I am not sure what is app_id, what is your_backend_environment_name and how can I use it in my Amplify project.

Comment: You can use Amplify CLI to generate secrets. 
https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/function/secrets/#configuring-secret-values. Make sure to update to the latest version of Amplify CLI to get this functionality.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you've already found the solution, but perhaps someone would search for the same.

You need to name your secret parameter as the docs suggest:

```
/amplify/{your_app_id}/{your_backend_environment_name}/{your_parameter_name}
```

To find the `{your_app_id}` and `{your_backend_environment_name}`, you want to go to the Amplify console in AWS. Click on your application, and notice the list of environments the application deployed to. In my example, I want to set the secret for Dev.

Click on the "Action" drop-down button on the top right corner, chose "View app settings". On the right hand you'll notice the "App ARN" in the next format:

```
arn:aws:amplify:eu-west-1:ACCOUNT_ID:apps/sdkjhf9shdfweh
```

"`sdkjhf9shdfweh`" part is your APP ID.

If I want to set a secret name `MY_SECRET` I'd need to go to the parameter store and create a secret string parameter with the following name:

```
/amplify/sdkjhf9shdfweh/dev/MY_SECRET
```

Then I'll be able to access it from the build pipeline.

Comment: Please read "[How do I format my posts...](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)"
"[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/)"

Comment: Hi! How should I access secret variables from my `amplify.yml` file? [Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/environment-variables.html) explain how to access normal environment variables like: `$MY_VARIABLE`, but how do I access `MY_SECRET`?

Comment: Hey @ErnestoStifano ,
Amplify exports the secrets as json strings under `process.env.secrets`. 
So you can access them from your build via something like `${secrets.MYSECRET}`, or  `echo $secrets |jq -r -j '.MYSECRET'`

Comment: @ErnestoStifano I getting this error. I did setup variables in parameter store and  secret manager following this pattern `/amplify/{your_app_id}/{your_backend_environment_name}/{your_parameter_name} `
2022-07-28T05:59:19.815Z [INFO]: SSM params {"Path":"/amplify/adfcdefa6b6hx2/test/","WithDecryption":true}
2022-07-28T05:59:19.858Z [WARNING]: !Failed to set up process.env.secrets
2022-07-28T06:00:10.900Z [INFO]: BackendEnvironment name test for app adfcdefa6b6hx2 is invalid

Comment: I created a fresh environment on Amplify and also created a parameter in SSM. Unfortunately the build process in Amplify indicates following log

[WARNING]: !Failed to set up process.env.secrets

Due to this, I am not able to refer any secrets configured in SSM. Any clue??

Comment: @CuriousMind Were you able to find a solution for this issue?

Comment: @CurlyError I was able to read the SSM parameter. But there is a known issue with SSM integration with Amplify - https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-hosting/issues/3258

Comment: @CuriousMind would you be able to share your solution as an answer, looks like the implementation is still unclear in the aws docs.

Comment: @ConnorWilloughby If you have named the variables correctly and still not able to access the variable, then you must check the IAM role assigned to Amplify application. It should have full permissions to SSM.